# MSP430, impossible to use UART no Output with Putty

Tags: putty, uart, msp430

everybody,

currently working with the MSP430FR2433, my goal is to use UARTs to transmit a message. I am at the beginning of this project so my current goal is to send only one message between two UARTs on the same launchpad. You will find below the code, it contains the hardware initialization (clock, UART etc...). However, there is no result, Putty which seems to be correctly configured (bauds, port, flow control) does not observe anything when it is put into serial mode. I'm sorry for the length of the code... And hope to have some help, in advance thank you very much.

```
#include <msp430fr2433.h>
#include "driverlib/MSP430FR2xx_4xx/driverlib.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "C:/ti/ccsv8/tools/compiler/ti-cgt-msp430_18.1.3.LTS/include/string.h"
#include "C:/ti/ccsv8/tools/compiler/ti-cgt-msp430_18.1.3.LTS/include/time.h"
#include "C:/ti/ccsv8/tools/compiler/ti-cgt-msp430_18.1.3.LTS/include/stdio.h"


#define DCOFREQ 8000000 //8MHz

#define TXLED BIT0
#define RXLED BIT6
#define MAX_STRBUF_SIZE 1024

void systemInit(void);
void initCs(void);
void initEusci(void);
void initEusci1(void);
void UART_receiveString(char);
void UART_transmiteString1(char*);
void UART_transmiteString(char*);



bool rxStringReady;
char rxString[MAX_STRBUF_SIZE];
char txString1[MAX_STRBUF_SIZE] = {"ok"}; // 0110 1111 01101011



volatile uint32_t i; // Used in the main function in the for loop



int iii = 0;

int main(void)
{
   systemInit(); // System initialization

   UART_transmiteString1(txString1);

   while(1)
       {
           UART_transmiteString1(txString1);

           for(i=100000; i>0; i--);

      }

}

void systemInit(void)
{

   // Stop watchdog timer
   WDT_A_hold(WDT_A_BASE);
   printf("Hello in System Init\n");

   // Initialization of the clock
   initCs();

   // LED output
   P1DIR |= RXLED + TXLED;
   P1OUT &= 0x00;

   // Disable the GPIO power-on default high-impedance mode to activate
   // previously configured port settings
   PM5CTL0 &= ~LOCKLPM5;

   //Initialization of the UARTs.
   initEusci();
   initEusci1();

   // Enable gobal interrupts
  __enable_interrupt();
}


void initCs(void)
{
   // Initialization of the clocks
   CS_initClockSignal(CS_SMCLK, CS_DCOCLKDIV_SELECT, CS_CLOCK_DIVIDER_1);

   // For demonstration purpose, change DCO clock freq to 8MHz
   CS_initFLLSettle((DCOFREQ/1000), (DCOFREQ/32768));
}



// EUSCI 0
void initEusci(void)
{
   // Configure UCA1TXD and UCA1RXD
  P1SEL0 |= BIT4 | BIT5;
  P1SEL1 &= ~(BIT4 | BIT5);

  // Configure UART
  // http://software-dl.ti.com/msp430/msp430_public_sw/mcu/msp430/MSP430BaudRateConverter/index.html
  // 115 200 bps this value depends on the transmitter used
   EUSCI_A_UART_initParam param = {0};
   param.selectClockSource = EUSCI_A_UART_CLOCKSOURCE_SMCLK;
   param.clockPrescalar = 4;
   param.firstModReg = 5;
   param.secondModReg = 85;
   param.parity = EUSCI_A_UART_NO_PARITY;
   param.msborLsbFirst = EUSCI_A_UART_LSB_FIRST;
   param.numberofStopBits = EUSCI_A_UART_ONE_STOP_BIT;
   param.uartMode = EUSCI_A_UART_MODE;
   param.overSampling = EUSCI_A_UART_OVERSAMPLING_BAUDRATE_GENERATION;

   if(STATUS_FAIL == EUSCI_A_UART_init(EUSCI_A0_BASE, &param))
   {
       return;
   }

   EUSCI_A_UART_enable(EUSCI_A0_BASE);

   // Interruption
   EUSCI_A_UART_clearInterrupt(EUSCI_A0_BASE, EUSCI_A_UART_RECEIVE_INTERRUPT);

   // Enable USCI_A0 RX interrupt
   EUSCI_A_UART_enableInterrupt(EUSCI_A0_BASE, EUSCI_A_UART_RECEIVE_INTERRUPT); // Enable interrupt
}

// EUSCI interrupt service routine 0
#if defined(__TI_COMPILER_VERSION__) || defined(__IAR_SYSTEMS_ICC__)
#pragma vector=USCI_A0_VECTOR
__interrupt void USCI_A0_ISR(void)
#elif defined(__GNUC__)
void __attribute__ ((interrupt(USCI_A0_VECTOR))) USCI_A0_ISR (void)
#else
#error Compiler not supported!
#endif
{
   printf("i m before the switch\n");
   switch(__even_in_range(UCA0IV,USCI_UART_UCTXCPTIFG))
   {
   printf("i m in the switch\n");

       case USCI_NONE: break;

       // Function which run the halt
       case USCI_UART_UCRXIFG:

           // Read buffer
           UART_receiveString(UCA0RXBUF);

           // Write in buffer
           UART_transmiteString(rxString);
           break;
       case USCI_UART_UCTXIFG: break;
       case USCI_UART_UCSTTIFG: break;
       case USCI_UART_UCTXCPTIFG: break;
       default: break;
   }
}

void UART_receiveString(char data)
{
  printf("%c\n", data);
   bool rxInProgress = false;
   unsigned int charCnt = 0;

   if(!rxInProgress) // if it's wrong, start the interruption with this condition
   {
       if ((data != '\n') )  // if it's a new line, the value of the timer change to 0.
       {
           rxInProgress = true;
           charCnt = 0;
           rxString[charCnt] = data;
       }
   }
   else
   { // in progress
       charCnt++;
       if((data != '\n'))
       {
           if (charCnt >= MAX_STRBUF_SIZE) // If it has come to transmit a length greater than MAX_STRBUF_SIZE to read the data.
           {
               rxInProgress = false;
           }
           else
           {
               rxString[charCnt] = data;  // Read the data and write them in a table.

           }
       }
       else
       {
           rxInProgress = false;
           rxString[charCnt] = '\0';
           // String receive complete
           rxStringReady = true;
       }
   }
}


void UART_transmiteString(char *str)
{
   int ii = 0;
   for(ii = 0; ii < strlen(str); ii++)
   {
       if (str[ii] != 0)
       {
           // Transmit Character
           while (EUSCI_A_UART_queryStatusFlags(EUSCI_A0_BASE, EUSCI_A_UART_BUSY));
           EUSCI_A_UART_transmitData(EUSCI_A0_BASE, str[ii]);
       }
   }
}




// EUSCI 1
void initEusci1(void) {

   // Configure UCA1TXD and UCA1RXD
   P2SEL0 |= BIT6 | BIT5;
   P2SEL1 &= ~(BIT6 | BIT5);

   // Configure UART
   // http://software-dl.ti.com/msp430/msp430_public_sw/mcu/msp430/MSP430BaudRateConverter/index.html
   EUSCI_A_UART_initParam param = {1};
   param.selectClockSource = EUSCI_A_UART_CLOCKSOURCE_SMCLK;
   param.clockPrescalar = 4;
   param.firstModReg = 5;
   param.secondModReg = 85;
   param.parity = EUSCI_A_UART_NO_PARITY;
   param.msborLsbFirst = EUSCI_A_UART_LSB_FIRST;
   param.numberofStopBits = EUSCI_A_UART_ONE_STOP_BIT;
   param.uartMode = EUSCI_A_UART_MODE;
   param.overSampling = EUSCI_A_UART_OVERSAMPLING_BAUDRATE_GENERATION;

   if(STATUS_FAIL == EUSCI_A_UART_init(EUSCI_A1_BASE, &param))
   {
       return;
   }

   EUSCI_A_UART_enable(EUSCI_A1_BASE);
   // Interruptions do not need to be enabled
}


void UART_transmiteString1(char *str1)
{
   int i1 = 0;
   printf("%d\n", strlen(str1));
   for(i1 = 0; i1 < strlen(str1); i1++)
   {
       if (str1[i1] != 0)
       {
           // Transmit Character
           while (EUSCI_A_UART_queryStatusFlags(EUSCI_A1_BASE, EUSCI_A_UART_BUSY));
           EUSCI_A_UART_transmitData(EUSCI_A1_BASE, str1[i1]);
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: Have you got at least one UART port working with PUTTY. Also check your ISR routine too.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a debugger and cycle with breakpoints through your code. Besides this download a reference code from TI (these are small), start small and extend your code step by step.